# Поиск строки в памяти СВОЕГО процесса

Tags: delphi

Как можно найти текстовую строку в памяти свего процесса, без использования `OpenProcess` / `ReadProcessMemory` ?

Comment: А в чем причина отказа от использования подобных функций? Если какая-то антидампинговая защита - попробуй проинжектить свой код в csrss.exe, а уже после из того процесса открывать необходимый и читать память. Ну если совсем худо - получи доступ к памяти процесса из ядра. Напиши свой драйвер, а уже через него получай доступ к оригинальным функциям ZwOpenProcess и ZwReadProcessMemory. Рекомендую почитать [Технологии дампинга и защиты от него][1]


  [1]: http://wasm.ru/article.php?article=dumping

Comment: Ну, скажем так, игрушка одна защищается, не даёт себе голдов и ресурсов нарисовать))
Её защита хучит всем приложениям очень многие функции из kernel32, kernelbase, ntdll, user32 и проверяет на желание залезть к её приложению в процесс, 44 хука я насчитал. Если их снимать - они через пару секунд снова ставятся, там вообще драйвера по-моему, которые выгружать не вариант - сразу всё упадёт. Но есть возможность работать прям изнутри её адресного пространства, скармливая ей длл

Comment: попробуй вариант подгрузить длл в csrss.exe, а уже из него - найти свой процесс и для своего процесса выпонить чтение/запись. По специфике, защита должна разрешать подобное иначе у нее могут возникнуть конфликты с операционкой. Это чтобы не заморачиваться с драйверами, может и получится реализовать.

Comment: А как в него заинжектиться?( Никакие стандартные инжект-функции туда не заинжекчивают, это ж виндовый процесс(

Comment: @Григорий Пономарёв да хотя-бы так: [пример][1]


  [1]: http://www.wasm.ru/article.php?article=fwb

Comment: Если бы я был автором "игрушки", то я ресурсы  хранил бы не в одном месте, а в нескольких. Причем не обязательно в явном виде. И когда приходит следующий этап обновления данных (пересчет, вывод на экран), делал бы проверку. Не совпадает - пересчет. Можно так сделать, что кол-во ресурсов будет очень хорошо размазано по памяти. На крайний случай - можно просто сделать копию ресурсов и зашифровать любым алгоритмом шифрования.

А драйвера, хуки, защиты - для отвода глаз и явных "школьников".

Comment: @KoVadim, а прозрачность и масштабируемость кода? а отладка и разбор багрепортов? а повторное использование кода? а то что спецы в разработке кода игры в 80% случаев не являются специалистами в области информационной безопасности и на порядок проигрывают крекерам? разделение труда также нужно учитывать. не очень-то и эффективен предложенный тобой вариант, особенно для действительно больших по обьему кода игр.

Comment: @KoVadim, в моём случае разработчик игры и разработчик защиты - две разные компании. Защита используется не для одного единственного продукта, а вот такая массовость и гибкость качеству не способствуют. И полностью согласен с @vv2cc, ваш способ хорош для своего небольшого проекта, но никак не для 6-гигабайтной игры.

Comment: фразы "6 Гб игра" меня шокируют. Я думаю, что Вы понимаете, что 5 с половиной гигов занимают всякие ресурсы, а не код. А собственно сам код занимает в лучшем случае 100Мб. Хватит измерять крутость игры размерами.

Внешняя защита это хорошо. Она выполняет свои функции. Внутренняя - свои. То, что я описал, можно написать за пару дней и отладить. Более того, такой код даже поможет отладке.

Если код, отвечающий за "голд" размазан по 100 файлам, то такой код будет поддерживать очень сложно, а отлаживать тем более. Поэтому он локальный.

Разработчикам игр не нужно быть мегаспецами в безопасности.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim), что мешает в момент обновления записи о количестве голда, поймать эвент и изменить значение? Код-то можно проанализировать в отладчике, дизассемблере и т.д. А в игре, потребляющей и без того большое количество рессурсов системы, за это могут не погладить по голове. В любой системе защиты есть узкие места, особенно если данные хранятся и обрабатываются на стороне клиента.Уж лучше на сервак такую часть переносить, но это уже флуд.  ПС. закончились коменты :)

Comment: И хотя свою проблему я уже решил иначе, вопрос так и остался открытым :-D

Ну, вот допустим, у меня есть своё приложение и я хочу найти в его адресном пространстве строку или значение байт. Чтобы считать из своего адресного пространства,

B := Byte(Pointer(Address)^);
S := PAnsiChar(Address);

могу сделать так

h := OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, False, GetCurrentProcessId); // или GetCurrentProcess
ReadProcessMemory(h, Ptr(address), @B, 1, c);

Или вот так.

Но какой мне смысл в моём же приложении работать с памятью через ReadProcessMemory, когда можно напрямую?

Comment: @Григорий Пономарёв, начнем с самого подхода: 

откуда тебе известен адресс где располагаются необходимые тебе данные?

если адресс достоверно известен, то внутри процесса ты легко можешь к нему обратиться(а он доступен исходя из контекста задачи)

вопрос - как найти необходимый тебе адресс?

решение: определить блоки памяти процесса и их аттрибуты. для 
каждого блока виртуальной памяти у которого есть доступ на чтение и запись выполнить первичное сканирование. в последующем - отсев, если нужно.(artmoney - наглядный пример). 

Вот тут-то и нужны функции для работы с вирт. памятью процесса.